# Series generation

Tags: java, series, factorial

I am trying to find out the sum of the series, 1/2! - 2/3! + 3/4! - 4/5! ... n. Sorry if this sounds awkward but the sum always shows up as 0.0. I can't figure out what's happening and I am just starting out. Can anyone kindly point out the mistake and suggest how to fix it? Thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Series {
    /*
     * Series design: 1/2! - 2/3! + 3/4! - 4/5! .. n 
    */
    static double sum = 0; static int n;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int fact(int n){
        int fact = 1; 
        for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
            fact *= i;
        }
        return fact;
    }
    void generate(){
        double sign = 1.0; double term;
        for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
            term = i/fact(i+1) * sign;
            sum += term;
            sign *= -1;
        }
    }
    void accept(){
        System.out.println("Enter the value of n:");
        n = sc.nextInt(); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Series o = new Series();
        o.accept();
        o.generate();
        System.out.println("The sum of the series is: " +sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: integer division.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`i` and `fact(i+1)` are both `int`s, so you're performing [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Of_integers). Since `i < fact(i+1)`, each such term will produce a zero.

You had the right idea with defining `sign` as a `double`, but since `/` and `*` have the same precedence, you're first performing an integer division and only then multiplying by the double `sign`. Moving it to the beginning of the expression should do the trick:

```
void generate(){
    double sign = 1.0; double term;
    for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        term = (sign * i) / fact(i+1);
        sum += term;
        sign *= -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `i/fact(i+1)` is an `int` division, so it is truncated to 0 (since it's smaller than 1).

Change it to `(double)i/fact(i+1)`.

Alternately, you can write

```
term = sign*i/fact(i+1);
```

since `sign` is already double, so it would ensure `sign*i` would also be double, and the division would be a floating point division.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Series {


    static double sum = 0.0;
    static int n=0;
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static int fact(int n)
    {
       int fact = 1; 

      for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){

        fact *= i;
    }
    return fact;
   }

    static void generate(){
     //because of static property

     double sign = 1.0; double term;
     for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        term = (i* sign)/fact(i+1) ;
        sum += term;
        sign *= -1;
     }
}
     static void  accept(){

       //because of static property

       System.out.println("Enter the value of n:");
       n = sc.nextInt(); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Series.accept();
    Series.generate();
    System.out.println("The sum of the series is: " +sum);
}
}
```